# Mouse stops working

Tags: 20.04, mouse

Sometimes my mouse stops working (SPC LIX). I have tried updating upgrading but it still does happen. I'm on ubuntu 20.04

PC specs:
i7 11gen
16GB RAM
SPC LIX mouse

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat. The left mouse button ceases to work.
This seems to be a "feature" of Ubuntu since you can find it happening since at least version 10.

The usual solution (if it works) is stopgap.

Solution #1
alt-F1 puts you in text mode
alt-F7 puts you back in graphics (and restores mouse .... maybe)

Solution #2
sudo modprobe -r psmouse;
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps

There have been other "solutions"

And there is always a reboot which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Ubuntu 20.04 with another mouse and see if the problem is replicated. If the problem is replicated with another mouse try booting any live USB, for example the live USB that you used to install Ubuntu to check if there is something wrong with your installed Ubuntu 20.04.

If both the live and the installed OSs have the same problem with the mouse and the problem is also replicated with a different mouse, then maybe there is a hardware issue with the USB port that the mouse is connected to. Sometimes when you think you have the mouse plugged in to the USB port it is not plugged in to the USB port all the way, and this can cause the mouse to stop working intermittently.

You can also either change the USB port or try connecting a wireless mouse instead of a cable-connected mouse. A wireless mouse connects to your computer via Bluetooth wireless technology, a USB unifying receiver, or both depending on the model of the mouse.